# Read even lines from a file in assembly

Tags: assembly, lines

I have to read the name of a file from the keyboard input, and then to print on the screen the even lines from this file
I did open the file using the 3dh function of int 21h, but my question is how to read line by line in order to print only the even lines? I did not exactly understand how to use carriage return or line feed. Here's what i've done so far:

```
assume cs:code, ds:data
data segment
    msg db 'Give the name of the file: $'
    fileName db 12,?,13 dup (?)
    buffer db 21 dup (?)
    openErrorMsg db 'The file does not exist.$'
    handler dw 0
data ends
code segment
start:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset msg
    int 21h 

    mov ah, 0ah
    mov dx, offset fileName
    int 21h

    mov bl, fileName[1]
    mov bh, 0
    add bx, offset fileName
    add bx, 2
    mov byte ptr [bx], 0

    mov ah, 3dh
    mov al, 0
    mov dx, offset fileName+2
    int 21h

    jc openError 
    ; ?? - 

openError:
        mov ah, 09h
        mov dx, offset openErrorMsg
        int 21h
        jmp endPrg
    endPrg:
        mov ah, 3eh
        mov bx, handler
        int 21h

        mov ax,4c00h
        int 21h

code ends
end start
```

Comment: Don't forget to save the returned handle as your first action at the point where you are apparantly stuck. Then use the advice given by Dirk Wolfgang Glomp to process the file.

Answer (score 1):

The carriage return(0Dh) and the line feed(0Ah) are some of the control characters in ASCII code. The carriage return commands a printer, or other output system such as a display, to move the position of the cursor to the first position on the same line. And the line feed move the cursor to the next line, so that together they start a new line. If the output is in the last line, then the content of the screen is scrolling upwards and the ouput starts in a new empty last line.

If we only want to print the even lines of a text file, then we have to compare the text byte by byte for to find the sequence of "0Dh, 0Ah", or at minimum the byte of "0Dh". Note: A linux text file includes only "0Dh" without  "0Ah". For using the DOS teletype output function, we have to put a "$" behind the text that we want to print.

For to load the file we can use the DOS read function. I prefer to load the whole text file into the ram in one step and for comparing and for printing the even lines within another step. But alternative we can load only single bytes for comparing and printing in one step and then loading the next single byte in a next step and so on.

RBIL->inter61b.zip->INTERRUP.F

```
--------D-213F-------------------------------
INT 21 - DOS 2+ - "READ" - READ FROM FILE OR DEVICE
AH = 3Fh
BX = file handle
CX = number of bytes to read
DS:DX -> buffer for data
Return: CF clear if successful
    AX = number of bytes actually read (0 if at EOF before call)
CF set on error
    AX = error code (05h,06h) (see #01680 at AH=59h/BX=0000h)
Notes:  data is read beginning at current file position, and the file position
  is updated after a successful read
the returned AX may be smaller than the request in CX if a partial
  read occurred
if reading from CON, read stops at first CR
under the FlashTek X-32 DOS extender, the pointer is in DS:EDX
BUG:    Novell NETX.EXE v3.26 and 3.31 do not set CF if the read fails due to
  a record lock (see AH=5Ch), though it does return AX=0005h; this
  has been documented by Novell
SeeAlso: AH=27h,AH=40h,AH=93h,INT 2F/AX=1108h,INT 2F/AX=1229h
```